# In C I can initialize a typedef struct using an array of bytes, but in C++ I can't, Is there a way to get around that?

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, arduino

I'm writing code to communicate to microcontrollers using serial (UART).
I receive data that can be arranged in many different configurations.
Some packets may contain floats, others just chars. etc.

Here is what I have in C and it works just fine:

```c
 #define packed __attribute__((packed))

//this is a typedef struct I used, 

    typedef struct packed {
                  uint8_t cmd; 
                  uint8_t src_uart; 
                  uint8_t dst_uart;
                  void* stuff;}const * P_generic_t;

//then i do the following to extract formatted info from my buffer
//where pbuf->payload is an array of uint8_t(aka unsigned char)

P_generic_t cg = (void *) pbuf->payload;
```

Then I can simply access the member of the struct by doing `cg->cmd` or `cg->src_uart`. In C++ however this method doesn't work.

The reason why I'm using C++ now is because I want to use this code on an Arduino for a side project, and I want a reliable way to extract data from my buffer in an efficient way. I get the following error:

```
comclass.cpp:82: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'P_simple_t {aka const<anonymous struct>*}' [-fpermissive]
```

I've also tried to run this code using the compiler on cloud9 and I get a similar error. Is there a way to initialize my struct as I did in C? Or is there a better option?

I know there is a way to run a specific part of the code as C, using `extern 'C'`, (sorry I don't know the syntax). Is that an option?

Comment: "this method doesn't work" what *exactly* have you tried? Show real code and any compiler output

Comment: `(void *) pbuf->payload` -> `(P_generic_t)pbuf->payload`. C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion to and from `void*` as freely as C does.

Comment: Never ever `typedef` pointers to datatypes (is typing a `*` reall ymore complicated than typing `P_`??)! And using the `const` qualifier after the type-specificer makes it harder to read. And don't use casts unless you really need them and know all implications. Said that: why do you expect two different languages behave the same, just because the happen to use the same syntax here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

`P_generic_t cg = (void *) pbuf->payload;`

You're casting `void*` to `P_generic_t`. Just as the compiler error says. The solution is to change the `(void*)` cast to `(P_generic_t)`. Or if you want to go full C++, use `static_cast` to `P_generic_t`.